# How to parse regex

Tags: regex

Does anybody know how to parse a string below to get these two strings: `[Test1][Test2]` and `[Test3][Test4]`.

STRING:

> `Hello [Test1][Test2] world] [Test3][Test4] this is test].`

Comment: More universal how? kdzwinel's answer works for the stated example. If you need to tackle a more complex input data you should improve the question, stackoverflow users aren't archmages. Please help us helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do a loop to get a dynamic number of matches (which I suppose that you want to get).

I used the pattern `.*?((?:\[.*?\])+)(.*)`. The first matching group will find the desired strings, the second matching group will always find "the rest", that you will have to parse again.

The construct "(?:   ...   )" is a non capturing group, which will not produce matching groups (in Java regular expression syntax).

Here is a short Java sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // define regular expression
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?((?:\\[.*?\\])+)(.*)");

    // iterate for each match
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Hello [Test1][Test2] world] [Test3][Test4] this is test].");
    while (matcher.matches()) {
        String text = matcher.replaceFirst(matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println("Found " + matcher.group(1));
        matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    }
}
```

That will output:

```
Found [Test1][Test2]
Found [Test3][Test4]
```

Sorry if this is kind of complicated, please let me/us know if you need a simpler example...

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `(\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+\]){2}` .

Comment: Thanks for reply. Your variant works perfectly just in this case. But I would like to get more universal method.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `perl` flavour regex:

```
m/\[\S+/g
```

---

Test:

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

## Read all data after __DATA__ filehandle.
while ( <DATA> ) { 

    ## Save in array '@matches' any characters from an opening 
    ## square bracket until a blank found.
    ## 'g' flag means to do it many times in same line.
    my @matches = m/\[\S+/g;

    ## Print to output. Each match in a line.
    printf qq[%s\n], join qq[\n], @matches;
}

__DATA__
Hello [Test1][Test2] world] [Test3][Test4] this is test].
```

Run the script:

```
perl script.pl
```

Result:

```
[Test1][Test2]
[Test3][Test4]
```